# Prefer no parenthesis on object initializers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editorconfig

Is there a way to prefer/enforce style when using object initializer to not use parenthesis using editorconfig?

```
// prefer
new Foo
{

};

// instead of
new Foo()
{

};
```

Comment: The only rule that I found in the editorconfig was the `dotnet_style_object_initializer` rule, that just prefers objects to be initialized using object initializers but it still uses parenthesis because that's how the language was specified and I don't think this would be doable at all with editorconfig.

Comment: Still an issue, found the feature request on GitHub:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39791